# Pass Changes from a Reusable Component inside another Resuable component

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

I came across a beautiful library called `Cupertino-Pane`, it just like a drawer that open from the bottom, just like when you click the options icon on `Twitter` that bottom Drawer that is draggable. For more info: [`https://github.com/roman-rr/cupertino-pane`](https://github.com/roman-rr/cupertino-pane)

I have got a logic that I want to implement, since I will be using the pane in some cases in my application, I decided to make it a reusable component, like this:

```
import { CupertinoPane } from "cupertino-pane";
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { PanelProps } from "../../interfaces";

const IonDrawer = ({ panelKey, show, children }: PanelProps) => {
  const drawerRef = useRef<CupertinoPane>();

  const hidePanel = async () => {
    console.log("Tapped");
    await drawerRef.current?.hide();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    drawerRef.current = new CupertinoPane(`.${panelKey}`, {
      backdrop: true,
      bottomClose: true,
      buttonClose: false,
      parentElement: "body",
      fastSwipeClose: true,
      fitHeight: true,
      onBackdropTap: () => hidePanel(),
    });
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const showPanel = async () => {
      await drawerRef.current?.present({ animate: true });
    };

    if (show) {
      showPanel();
    } else {
      hidePanel();
    }
  });

  return <div className={panelKey}>{children}</div>;
};

export default IonDrawer;
```

This is the Main Pane. `onBackdropTap`, I want to always disable the Panel.

Now this component is now used by another reusable component.

```
const Feed: FC<FeedProps> = ({
   .....
  panelKey,
  ......
}) => {
  const slideRef = useRef<HTMLIonSlidesElement>(null);
  const [show, setShow] = useState<boolean>(false);
    
        <IonDrawer show={show} panelKey={panelKey}>
                  <h3>John Doe</h3>
                </IonDrawer>
        
                    <IonButton className="btn" fill="clear" color="secondary">
                      <div className="d-flex align-center">
                        <IoEllipsisHorizontalCircleOutline
                          size="20"
                         // ShowPane When Button is Clicked, then Hide When Backdrop is Clicked, But i got confused
                          onClick={() => setShow(true)}
                        />
                      </div>
                    </IonButton>
```

In my HomeComponent, The Feed Component is rendered like this

```
const Feed1: FeedContent = {
  ...OtherProps
  panelKey: "panel-1",
};

const Feed2: FeedContent = {
  ...otherProps
  panelKey: "panel-2",
};

 <Feed {...Feed1} />
 <Feed {...Feed2} />
```

I want to show the Pane when The Above Button is clicked and disable it when the `backDrop` is tapped in the `IonDrawer`, but when backdrop is clicked `show` does not go to `false`.

When the BackDrop is Tapped from The IonDrawer, how do I know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tricky But Solved!!!

i passed a callback Function as a prop on the `IonDrawer component,` like so:

```
  onClosePanel,
```

Then the function calls the

```
hidepanel() function:

onClosePanel(() => {
      hidePanel();
    });
```

while using IonDrawer in another component,

```
                 <IonDrawer
                    show={show}
                   ....
                    onClosePanel={() => setShow(false)}
                  >
                    <IonItem>
                      <IonLabel>Join</IonLabel>
                      <p>dddndndndbdb</p>
                      <IonLabel>Join</IonLabel>
                    </IonItem>
                  </IonDrawer>
```